# Prevent Auto code change in Designer.cs for a specific line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I made a simple change in Designer.cs which is

```
this.dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
```

but whenever i do some change in form design `DateTime.Now` is replaced by current DateTime value. How to prevent this automatic code change?

Comment: Never edit generated code. This is exactly what happens.

Comment: That is a Visual Studio issue. On Borland products I did not see that awful thing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not change code in the InitializeComponent method as it is auto-generated and will be replaced when you make changes in the designer. The method summary says it all:

> do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor

Place your code in the constructor of your code-behind file instead (after the call to InitializeComponent). This will set the value and override any value that may have been specified in the InitializeComponent method:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bling
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dateTimePicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the thing i am doing afterall