# How to replace hardcoded string for label text in *.Designer.cs C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hardcode

How  can I correctly replace hardcoded string for labels in Form1.Designers.cs?

Instead of:

```
        this.button1.Text = "TheButton";
        this.label1.Text = "TheLabel";
```

I want to write:

```
        this.button1.Text = Resources.ButtonText;
        this.label1.Text = Resources.LabelText;
```

After changing form in visual designer (add any component and save) VS code generator turns back label text to hardcoded string:

```
        this.button1.Text = Resources.ButtonText;
        this.label1.Text = "TheLabel";
```

Is anybody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: So you write `Resources.LabelText;` and VS turns it back to `"TheLabel";`. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, it happens after changing form in designer.

Comment: Put it in the form constructor. The designer regenerates the code and will wipe out your changes.

Comment: Autogenerator doesn't wipe out replacing for button text. i.e. this.button1.Text = Resources.ButtonText remains after form changing in designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prevent Auto code change in Designer.cs for a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548316/prevent-auto-code-change-in-designer-cs-for-a-specific-line)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
       public Form1()
         {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.button1.Text = Resources.ButtonText;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not good solution for me. I would like to see label's text in designer and also I don't want to duplicate any code. 
For buttons replacing of hardcoded strings works perfect but for labels don't.

Comment: Sad, but I didn't find better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to make your own `Button`/`Label`, where it takes its `Text` property from `Resources`:

```
class MyButton: Button
{
    // put here attributes to stop its serialization into code and displaying in the designer
    public new string Text
    {
        get {return base.Text;}
        set {base.Text = value;}
    }

    public MyButton() : base()
    {
        base.Text = Resources.ButtonText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to prevent the reversion of the reference in the designer.cs file.

Instead of

```
this.label1.Text = MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.gui_lable1_text;
```

make it

```
this.label1.Text = global::MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.gui_lable1_text;
```